# R: Find similar columns of a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix with several columns containing signals. Some columns are very similar (but not equal), in that they share the highest values, and differ only by the lowest values (noise). I would like to keep just one column for each of them, but I would not know how to do it. 
For example, starting from the following matrix:

```
1     150     0     2     150
25    100     25    25    100
170   30      170   170   30
230   6       230   230   5
```

I would like to be left with just

```
1    150
25   100
170  30
230  6
```

Any  smart idea?

This is what I tried so far:
If my matrix is "x", I created the matrix "a":

`a <- apply(x, 2, function(p){tail(sort(p),3)})`

And then I removed the equal columns:

```
b <- unique(a, MARGIN = 2)
```

But then I do not know how to proceed

Comment: Try `a <- apply(x, 2, function(x) sd(sort(x)[-1]));x[tapply(seq_along(a), a, FUN=head,1)]`

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, which is not fully fleshed out yet. You could probably use clustering for this:

```
mat <- read.table(text="1     150     0     2     150
25    100     25    25    100
170   30      170   170   30
230   6       230   230   5")
mat <- as.matrix(mat)
d <- dist(t(mat), method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
fit <- hclust(d, method = "ward.D2") 
plot(fit)
```

[image: resulting plot]

If it is a hard requirement that only the minimum values are allowed to differ, you'd need to check the clusters for that. Maybe other distances or clustering algos could work even better ...